# Change icon when click

Tags: html, angular

I tried to set a spinner when I click to download a file. However, the spinner loads for all the downloaded files in the table row instead of just the one clicked.

Before click to download file 
[image]

After click to download file
[image]

**HTML**

```
 <td class="text-center px-1">
          <a class="text-dark" title="Download document" style="cursor: pointer"
             (click)="download(documentFiles.id, documentFiles.attachedName)">
            <i *ngIf="!isLoading" class="far fa-file-pdf"></i>
            <i *ngIf="isLoading" class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" style= color:#572364></i>
          </a>
 </td>
```

Below is code for the download method in the ts

**download.ts**

```
download(id: number, attachedName: string)
{
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.newCustomerDocumentService.download(id, attachedName);
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.isLoading = false;
   }, 4000);
 }
```

Comment: That's probably because all `td` share the same `isLoading` attribute, you need to refactor your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-43yixg?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
<a class="text-dark" title="Download document" style="cursor: pointer" (click)="download(documentFiles.id, documentFiles.attachedName)">
    <i *ngIf="isLoadingFileId != documentFiles.id" class="far fa-file-pdf"></i>
    <i *ngIf="isLoadingFileId == documentFiles.id" class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" style= color:#572364></i>
</a>
```

You can refactor the icon class like this:

```
 <i [ngClass]="isLoadingFileId == documentFiles.id ? 'fas fa-spinner fa-spin' : 'far fa-file-pdf'"></i>
```

.ts

```
  isLoadingFileId: number;

  download(id: number, attachedName: string) {
    this.isLoadingFileId = id;
    this.newCustomerDocumentService.download(id, attachedName);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isLoadingFileId = null;
    }, 4000);
  }
```

Comment: Tries both ways and it works perfectly. Thank you Adrita

Answer (score 2):

Define `loadingDocument: string;` in your component.

Instead of `this.isLoading = true;`, try `this.loadingDocument = id`;

And replace `this.isLoading = false;` by `this.loadingDocument = null`

And replace `*ngIf="!isLoading"` by `*ngIf="documentFiles.id === loadingDocument"`

Comment: Wandrille, your answer is on point. I had to tweak some things and Bam! It works also. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

`isLoading` is shared on all rows in your table. you should use it on your row data like `documentFiles.isLoading`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `isLoading` flag in `documentFiles` object. Then it will work for individual rows.